# Adding a form to formset's child elements

Tags: django, nested-forms

I have a Message form, with basic fields:

```
class MessageForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Message
        fields = [
            'message_introduction',
                  'recipient',
                  'sender'

        ]
        labels = {
            'message_introduction': 'message_introduction',
            'recipient':'recipient',
            'sender':'sender',

        }
```

Each message can contain multiple question by formset:

```
class Message_questionForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Message_question
        fields = ['message_question',
                  'recipient',
                  'sender'
                  ]
        widgets = {
            'message_question': forms.Textarea(attrs={'class': 'formset-field', 'rows': 4}),
        }
```

So far it all works well, i am able to call the form in the view and save both models with no problem.

I am now looking, in the detail view of each message, to display each question related to the message (that is done), but i would like to also add a way for the recipient to answer the question.

I have created my model:

```
class Question_answer(models.Model):
    message_question = models.ForeignKey(Message_question, related_name="question_answers", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    question_answer = models.TextField()
    recipient = models.CharField(blank=True, null=True, max_length=255)
    sender = models.CharField(blank=True, null=True, max_length=255)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.question_answer
    class Meta:
        db_table = 'question_answers'
```

But from here I am not sure how to proceed in the viewz.py and in the actual template.
Would someone know a way to put an answer field in front of each question please ?

Comment: [This](https://swapps.com/blog/working-with-nested-forms-with-django/) and [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/forms/modelforms/#inline-formsets) might help

Comment: @bdbd, thank you vm, this is exactly where I stand now.